# How can I get the type of a keyof variable in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```
interface MyInterface { 
   a: string 
   b: number 
}
```

and the following Function:

```
function myFunction(key: keyof MyInterface, someItem: MyInterface) {
  if (key === "a") {
    throw new Error("Key is not corresponding to a number")
  }
  
  return someItem[key]
}
```

It's working, but I have a much bigger interface and I'd like to avoid hardcoding all the keys, that don't correspond to a number. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get all the number keys with a type like this:

```
type NumberKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
```

Mapping over each key, we test if each key's value is a number. If it is, we map it to itself, otherwise, it's `never`.

Then finally, we get all of the results as a union with `[keyof T]`. Because `T | never` is always `T`, we only get the keys that are numbers left.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=12&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4GkIgM4B4AqAfFALxQDeAsAFBR1QDa6UAlgHZQDWWA9gGZR8AXQBcgpkKgQAHsAhsAJtihtEKVFAD8UZmLYQAbmgDcNAL4NuIfoKGnqNdnNR8AhgGNoAWRABJNs5unhQ09FB8PDxi2MCo7ADm9mFIrqh6aibmNDSgkDpYymTwyGiYOLg+-oEeEIT2APT19AB6mkA)